# clear form fields onLoad and onUnload on back button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the following code to clear the form fields when the back button is pressed. It works in IE7. But Firefox doesn't seem to be working. Here is my code. Please let me know if there are any suggestions. Thank you.

```
function clearForms()
{
  var i;
  for (i = 0; (i < document.forms.length); i++) {
    document.forms[i].reset();
  }
}

<body onLoad="clearForms()" onUnload="clearForms()">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use jQuery `$(document).ready()` instead of inline `onload` event handler.

```
$(document).ready(clearForms);
```

Comment: thanks for your help. Do you want me to this code in body tag?

Comment: No, just execute this code in a script block anywhere inside the body or head tag of the page but after jQuery is included.